# Finding which function cause the error message while processing a table

Tags: ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

by processing (Process Full,Process Data) a table (every table) in my cube, I get the following error:

```
Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'A function 'MAX' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.
A function 'MAX' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.
The credentials provided for the SQL source are invalid. (Source at XXXX;XXXX.). The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
```

How can I find which function cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query the `$SYSTEM.MDSCHEMA_MEASURES` DMV, which lists measures in a Tabular model.  The `Expression` column contains the definition of each measure, and you can use this to find any measures that have the `MAX` function that was specified in the error message.  SSAS DMVs can either be queried from an MDX query editor window in SSMS or another tool such as Dax Studio.  Dax Studio contains a listing of DMVs, and if you don’t already use it I’d recommend looking into this.  You here find more information on this [here](https://daxstudio.org/).  You can also execute your
measure in Dax Studio, which can help with
debugging it.  You will also want to verify that the account you’re using has the proper permissions on the SQL Server objects used by your Tabular model.